# Python: comparing a few thousand strings. Any fast alternatives for comparison?

Tags: python, string, performance, comparison, string-comparison

I have a set of around **6 000 packets** which for comparison purposes I represent as  **strings** (first 28 bytes) to compare against just as many packets, which I also represent as strings of 28 bytes.

I have to match each packet of one set with all of the other. **Matchings** are always **unique**.

I found that comparing strings takes a bit of time. Is there any way to **speed up** the process?

EDIT1: I wouldn't like to permutate string elements because I am always making sure that **ordering** between packet list and corresponding string list **is preserved**.

EDIT2: Here's my implementation:

```
list1, list2 # list of packets (no duplicates present in each list!)
listOfStrings1, listOfStrings2 # corresponding list of strings. Ordering is preserved.
alreadyMatchedlist2Indices = []
for list1Index in xrange(len(listOfStrings1)):
            stringToMatch = listOfStrings1[list1Index]
            matchinglist2Indices = [i for i, list2Str in enumerate(listOfStrings2)
                                if list2Str == stringToMatch and i not in alreadyMatchedlist2Indices]
            if not matchinglist2Indices:
                tmpUnmatched.append(list1Index)
            elif len(matchinglist2Indices) == 1:
                tmpMatched.append([list1Index, matchinglist2Indices[0]])
                alreadyMatchedlist2Indices.append(matchinglist2Indices[0])
            else:
                list2Index = matchinglist2Indices[0] #taking first matching element anyway
                tmpMatched.append([list1Index, list2Index])
                alreadyMatchedlist2Indices.append(list2Index)
```

Comment: Do you need to just tell if strings are different or to say what is different?

Comment: no no, I just need to know which two elements are exactly the same. Matchings I assume to be unique.

Comment: You should include your current implementation in order for people to be able to provide a faster alternative.

Comment: A decent hash function across 28 octets should be pretty good. Consider using the header strings as dictionary keys

Comment: Ok, I added the code I am using.

Answer (score 5):

---Here I'm assuming you're taking every strings one by one and comparing to all others.---

I suggest sorting your list of string and comparing neighboring strings. This should have a runtime of O(nlogn).

Comment: If the sorting is comparison-based, wouldn't this explode runtime?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say that I would like to keep the initial ordering of both lists. I'm making sure that for each `i` `listOfStrings[i] ` correspondonds to `listOfPackets[i]`

Comment: @Ricky Robinson: But perhaps you can sort `listOfStrings` and `listOfPackets` together. I mean when you swap two elements in one list, you swap the same way in the another while sorting. In this way you could ensure that `listOfStrings[i]` correspondonds to `listOfPackets[i]`.

Comment: If you're looking to copy the content you may use what senderle suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple linear time approach -- at least if I understand your question correctly:

```
>>> def get_matches(a, b):
...     reverse_map = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(b)}
...     return [(i, reverse_map[x]) for i, x in enumerate(a) if x in reverse_map]
... 
>>> get_matches(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e'])
[(2, 0)]
```

This accepts two sequences of strings, `a` and `b`, and returns a list of matches represented as tuples of indices into `a` and `b`. This is O(n + m) where m and n are the lengths of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Note the space complexity of O(n) and also that runtime depends on the map implementation.

Comment: @LewisDiamond, as far as I know, all Python dictionary implementations use hash maps.

Comment: I updated my original post with my code. Is your suggested code snippet sensibly faster?

Comment: I would expect it to be a lot faster because `if x in reverse_map` is a constant-time operation -- testing for a key in a Python dictionary almost never requires more than one or two comparisons. So given two 6000-item lists, your code does thirty-six million loops (6000 * 6000) while this function only does twelve thousand loops (6000 + 6000).

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with:

```
matches = [packet for packet in list1 if packet in list2]
```

Comment: I use `Scapy` and it takes forever if I use packet structures directly. Are there any "lighter" alternatives?